# How to create loop templates in php

Tags: php, c++

As we can define loop templates in C++, for making coding shorter:

```
#define fo(a,b,c) for( a = ( b ); a < ( c ); ++ a )
```

Is there any way to do the same in PHP?

Comment: This is a horrifically bad thing to do, and everybody would much prefer it if such a thing were never done.

Comment: I just asked if it is possible to do or not. Horror and all comes later.

Comment: @XEO - its better to delete my profile from this website, because i didnt join this website to increase my popularity or anything as such. I just want to learn. So instead of rephrasing the question, please tell me the procedure to close my profile.

Comment: [Can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999)

Comment: @all - I am sorry for being so rude. I shouldnt have behaved like this. Pardon me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Well, this is not exactly preprocessor macro, but due to "dynamic" nature of PHP, preprocessors are not needed/used. Instead however, you are able to wrap functions in other functions, like in the example below.

Yes, you can do this by creating your own function that is being passed also a callback. Here is the example:

```
// FO function
function fo($b, $c, $callback) {
    for ($a = $b; $a < $c; ++$a) {
        $callback($a);
    }
}

// example of usage
fo(2,10, function($a){
    echo '['.$a.']';
});
```

The above code works in PHP 5.3 and outputs the following:

```
[2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]
```

Comment: @Tadeck : Not only is there a difference between macros and wrapping functions inside each other, but calling a function inside another doesn't always generate the same result. For example, executing a function "debug" defined as "function debug($code, $message) { return trigger_error($message, $code); }" behaves differently from executing the function "trigger_error" directly, because the "errcontext" is different in both cases.

Comment: @griffin: Right, which is why Xeo should _not_ have modified the question to ask about preprocessor macros. The OP certainly did not ask about them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You are right, issue solved (reverted question to its original form).

Answer (score 12):

Thankfully not. There are plenty of horrible things you can do to make unreadable PHP, but that isn't one of them.

PHP doesn't use a preprocessor by default. Being a dynamic language, there isn't a build step for it to be run as part of. There are third party pre-processors you can use like [CCPP](http://code.metala.org/p/ccpp/), and of course you can write your own, but they are likely to change your workflows considerably.

An interesting preprocessor for PHP was [PiHiPi](http://web.archive.org/web/20110321161525/http://code.google.com/p/pihipi/) which tried to add useful features to the language like JSON like array syntax, rather than needing to write `array()` every time. Unfortunately, the author has pulled it.

Comment: @rjmunro, macros are cuddly. Embrace them. (I prefer simple text-replace ones.) PHP is a very neat language so there's less need for them than in other languages, but they're nifty for shortening and simplifying largish blocks of code, making it more readable. If Objective-C didn't have macros I'd become homicidal.

Comment: +1 for correct answer and additional info including links. On a sidenote: macros themself don't make code unreadable - it's the people who write unreadable code (with unreadable macros). e.g. you can write plenty of unreadable perl without macros ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
function my_macro($a, $b, $c) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);
  array_shift($args);

  return call_user_func_array("something_horrifically_long_involving_{$a}_{$b}_and_{$c}", $args);
}
```

Comment: While certainly a valid answer, I maybe edited out too much of the original question, as it involves opening a new scope directly after the macro. Brb, editing.

Comment: There is a nicer way to do similar things using anonymous functions (PHP>=5.3). See my answer.

Comment: -1 This is not the same as a macro, it's just calling a function by name runtime. Preprocessor macros are evaluated compile time (like C++ templates) which is the reason they can be useful. e.g. preprocessor constant addition can more easily be optimized than a function call

Answer (score 0):

[CCPP](http://code.metala.org/p/ccpp/#what) seems to be closest thing available:

```
#define macroFunction(op1,op2,op3) ((int)op1/((int)op2+(int)op3))
#define hash_hash # ## #
#define showCExamples 1

#if showCExamples
//Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation
#define MYCASE(item,id) \
case id: \
  item##_##id = id;\
break

switch(x) {
    MYCASE(widget,23);
}
```