# How to reduce PHP-Code?

Tags: php, oop

**I have to write the same piece of code again and again, and I'd like to know if there's a better way, or a shortcut**

I'm using php, and I have 3 classes:

```
class A{
  private $data = array( .... );
  protected function get($index){
        return $data[$index];
  }
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
    public function doSth(){
        echo A::get('index');
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to get data from the grandparent-class.

No problem, in except that I need to get data very often, and that the php-code gets extremly huge (the real classname is very long, and the getter-Functionname is very long)

**That's what I'm writing:**

```
databaseCore::getDataByIndex('name')
```

**In C I would use a preprocessor-makro like this:**

`#define DATA(x) databaseCore::getDataByIndex((x))`

**Is there an easy way to reduce the amount of code I have to write?**

Comment: use the $this variqble over static method calls in extended classes

Comment: you can just use DATA while writing it, and before you go use it, use Find'n'Replace to replace it with the real thing. just an idea.

Comment: If you're abstracting away the function name because it's too long, why not just shorten it?

Comment: @Sam Dufel: Even if I would shorten it to `DBcore::get('name')`, it would be a lot of code, and the function would get unreadable soon

Comment: Php is not C, it doesn't have macros. In java you have super-long method names all the time, too.

Comment: Unless there are other ways to `get` data than `ByIndex` `DBcore::get()` seems like a great short name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there preprocessor macros in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163053/are-there-preprocessor-macros-in-php)

Comment: `DBcore::get('name')` is *not* a lot of code.  If you start going any shorter than that, you sacrifice readability for typing speed.  Code is read many, many more times than it is written.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: That's true in most cases, but this is an basic example of one loc in my prog: `$stmt->execute(array(DBcore::get('id'), DBcore::get('name2), DBcore::get('address'), DBcore::get('something), DBcore::get('test));`
And now imagine this kind of code to be used several times per function...
(But I'm currently rewriting it, so the "get"-Method can return an array of several data at once)

Comment: "And now imagine this kind of code to be used several times per function" <-- that is you problem right there. Your method is doing too much.

Comment: what's wrong with just `$this->get('index')` if you are in child class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## intro

First of all, you're breaking the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) at the same time,

Thus, you'll will be facing similar problems over and over again.

## The LSP:

Your `A` server a purpose of a container, that simple stores a data. Then you extend this one, and end up breaking `is-a` relationship. This is because a container is not a hanlder. `has-a` is the way to go. You can [inject a container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to that `$handler`, via `constructor`

## The SRP:

Since your `C` serve 3 responsibilities at the same time, it definitely breaks the `Single Responsibility Principle`. The first one is `data container`, the second is something that does `B`, and the third is something that does `C`.

This is also known as `deep inheritance`, which obviously is a bad practice, until it satisfies the `SRP` and `LSP`.

An example, of how you can reduce code duplication, while adhering the `SRP`, `LSP` and `DI`.

```
class Container
{
    protected $container = array();
    
    public function setName($name)
    {
       $this->container['name'] = $name;
    }
    
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->container['name'];
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
       $this->container['age'] = $age;
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
       return $this->container['age'];
    }
}

class Handler
{
     protected $pdo;
     
     public function __construct($pdo)
     {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
     }

     public function fetchSomething(Container $container)
     {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` =:name AND `age` =:age";
          $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
          $stmt->execute(array(
              ':name' => $container->getName(),
              ':age'  => $container->getAge()
          ));

          return $stmt->fetch();
     }
}


$container = new Container();

$container->setName($_POST['name']);
$container->setAge($_POST['age']);

$handler = new Handler($pdo);

$stuff = $handler->fetchSomething($container);

print_r($stuff);
```

So, what would you gain here? The reuse-ability, thus reducing code duplication.

---

Since you also do `DBcore::get('foo')`, you might want to [read this article](http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html)

Comment: How were you able to find my problem and provide a solution, with this little information I gave you? I'm deeply impresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `$data` to `protected` and use it like,

```
$this->data['name'];
```